# SharePoint 2019 Security Token Service Application default connection type HTTPS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, service-application, security-token-service, service-applications, sts

Is it possible to change Security Token Service Application default connection type to HTTPS. If so, then how we can do that. As I cannot find https option in GUI (Central Admin)

On the Service Applications page in Central Administration, select the service application,
and then click Publish.

[image]

Same I can do for other application services like User Profile Service, Metadata Service etc.

[image]

Please I want to do this for security reasons. Forcing SharePoint to use default connection type to **HTTPS**

Comment: What do you see under "Published URL" section? In our SP2013 Farm, I see it's already https.

Comment: Yes all my web application are https

Comment: If you look at ...Topology/topology.svc , it's set to be htts, so I'm assuming when requests are coming from the remote server/farm, the topology.svc is called with https.

Comment: When you publish a service application for other farms to consume, it has to use a certificate. You can read [here](http://karthiksharepoint.blogspot.com/2015/04/publish-and-consume-sharepoint-service.html)

Comment: STS certificate is set already and as per central admin I can see it uses http as default connection

Comment: What is the _URI_ used? Even when the dropdown is 'http', the URI should be 'https' on that modal.

Comment: Let me check and come back

Comment: I checked with my SP2019. We have same settings as Milind. No https is available in dropdown

Comment: Same here no HTTPS so how can force SharePoint to use HTTPS